# How was this particle path effect done?

Tags: path, animation, adobe-after-effects, typefaces

Im trying to emulate https://dribbble.com/shots/7444078-Drip-Drop-Dribbble

It looks like some kind of unwind path action, with 2d particles. Ive looked at particle tutorials specifically but wanted to see what the approach would be to mimic this specific example.

Comment: ECAbrams youtube channel has a two good tutorials for similar animations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-SK5sdLwSM & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgwTO0-qDJ4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags in the dribble post say it all: *after effects* / *cell animation* / *frame by frame*. Also the link in the page [points to the page where you can buy the animation](https://animography.net/products/colloid), where it says (emphasis mine):

> Carefully crafted **frame-by-frame** animations are at the core of Colloid. Each character is formed from a dance between two colored liquids. The **hand-drawn** motion has tons of detail, like tiny drops with lifelike movement.

As commented by Joonas you can find tutorials [such as this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-SK5sdLwSM) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgwTO0-qDJ4) on the web. In the videos the author actually uses a combination of manually redrawing the shape every few frames + motion along a path + extra deformation to make the blob look more organic.